# Problem with rails environment in app run on JELASTIC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, jelastic

I got already deployed server on JELASTIC. The problem is that if I do a deploy, rails_env in /etc/nginx/ruby.env is setting up by itself on ROOT -- not production as I want to. Then my application crash, because rails cannot see a ROOT env in database.yml. The case is that i do not want to add ROOT on database.yml. I want to keep it as clean as possible so I want to deploy my app in production environment.
[image]
When I click on "edit project" i got sth like this:
[image]

Which says that context production is already in use (and it is, because THIS app is deployed in production mode, like you can see in previous screen). When i do not choose any application deployment type, i have blank selectbox with ROOT placeholder (which is apparently used as deployment type because rails_env in ruby.env is set like this).

I tried also deploy app from deployment manager:

[image]

which allow me to choose environment and deployment type and
tells me that this context is already in use and if I want to redeploy context
[image]

but it deploy also as a ROOT and i have to change manually nginx ruby.env and restart nginx to make it work.

Do you have any idea, what am I doing wrong?
Any suggestions?

Two more questions, why deploy hooks does not save (for example it run previous hooks even if i delete them and replace with simple "echo")

And last question is, can i somehow create new deployment type called "staging", becasue as we know "development", "production" and "test" are used to other things like staging. I need staging for other purposes, like for example disabling mailers for client test servers.

Comment: Additionaly i have app deployed in production mode, its "shows" hooks for production env, but run hooks for ROOT environment after deploy (checked in /var/lib/jelastic/hooks directory).

Comment: We were not able to reproduce neither deployment issue nor hooks issue on our test environment. Looks like this is a particular case or we do a reproduction in a wrong way. Please, write us filling the form https://jelastic.com/contact/ so that we can take a look onto your environment closely.